# Версия схемы БД

Tags: android

Есть программа которая использует БД. Версия схемы БД указывал 1. Теперь в БД в таблицу добавил новую колонку. Вопрос нужно ли поднимать версию схемы БД? И Если нужно, то у пользователей которые скачаю программу автоматом изменится и появится колонка в таблице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, поднимать версию БД нужно при каждом структурном изменении. Во-вторых, у пользователей со старой версией БД будет старая структура и обновление до новой нужно реализовывать, это называется миграция.

Более подробно можно почитать например [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/79-urok-39-onupgrade-obnovljaem-bd-v-sqlite.html)